# Replace Shutdown button in Windows Start menu with Restart Button

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

IS there anyway I can remove the Shutdown button from Windows Server and replace it with Restart button? I know how to disable/remove Shutdown button through Local Computer policy but I don't know how to replace it with Restart button

Comment: ok,as a revision to my previous question, even if there's no way to replace the shutdown button with Restart; Is there a way to remove "shutdown" list item from the Shutdown options dialog which opens up after you clicked the Shutdown button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not disable shutdown the Shutdown button and use a shortcut on your desktop or quicklaunch bar to restart?

> Right-click on your desktop and select
>   New> Shortcut
>
> In the Type the location of the item:
>   textbox enter
>   %windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -r
>
> The -r parameter is used to restart
>   the computer.
>
> The following two parameters can be
>   used with -r:
>   -f Forces running applications to close without warning.
>   -t xx Set timeout for restart to xx seconds.
>
> The following command would reboot the
>   computer instantly.
>   %windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -r -f
>   -t 00
>
> Click the Next > button and Name your shortcut.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I almost solved this problem. What I did is a combination of your solution and local computer policy setting. First removed shutdown button from start menu through local computer policy setting then I created a shortcut for restart in start menu by customizing(Taskbar properties>Start Menu>customize>Add) it. What you finally see in the start menu, is a restart button.

Comment: Great to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

We only leave the Log Off button on the start menu (set through Group Policy - User/Admin Templates/Start Menu and Taskbar).  All administrators are required to use the "shutdown" command line to either shutdown or restart the server.